# Porting Hook DLL Code from Delphi 2007 to delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, delphi-2007, delphi-xe3

I have a working hook dll code for a win32 application which I developed in Delphi 2007. Since then I have ported the application to Delphi xe3 but now the hook dll or the injection function doesn't work. The hook dll replaces winsock data send and retrieve functions for UDP and TCP. Please guide.

### Injection Function

```
Function InjectDll(Process: dword; ModulePath: PChar): boolean;
var
  Memory:pointer;
  Code: dword;
  BytesWritten: size_t;
  ThreadId: dword;
  hThread: dword;
  hKernel32: dword;
  Inject: packed record
            PushCommand:byte;
            PushArgument:DWORD;
            CallCommand:WORD;
            CallAddr:DWORD;
            PushExitThread:byte;
            ExitThreadArg:dword;
            CallExitThread:word;
            CallExitThreadAddr:DWord;
            AddrLoadLibrary:pointer;
            AddrExitThread:pointer;
            LibraryName:array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
          end;
begin

  Result := false;
  Memory := VirtualAllocEx(Process, nil, sizeof(Inject),
                           MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  if Memory = nil then Exit;

  Code := dword(Memory);
  Inject.PushCommand    := $68;
  inject.PushArgument   := code + $1E;
  inject.CallCommand    := $15FF;
  inject.CallAddr       := code + $16;
  inject.PushExitThread := $68;
  inject.ExitThreadArg  := 0;
  inject.CallExitThread := $15FF;
  inject.CallExitThreadAddr := code + $1A;
  hKernel32 := GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll');
  inject.AddrLoadLibrary := GetProcAddress(hKernel32, 'LoadLibraryA');
  inject.AddrExitThread  := GetProcAddress(hKernel32, 'ExitThread');
  lstrcpy(@inject.LibraryName, ModulePath);
  WriteProcessMemory(Process, Memory, @inject, sizeof(inject), BytesWritten);
  hThread := CreateRemoteThread(Process, nil, 0, Memory, nil, 0, ThreadId);
  if hThread = 0 then Exit;
  CloseHandle(hThread);
  Result := True;

end;
```

### Hook DLL

```
unit uMain;

interface

implementation

uses
  windows, SysUtils,
  advApiHook,
  Winsock2b;

const
  ModuleName = 'Main Dll Unit';

var
  // >> Replaced functions for intercepting UDP messages
    TrueSendTo      : function (s: TSocket; Buf : Pointer; len, flags: Integer; var addrto: TSockAddr;
                                tolen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    TrueWsaRecvFrom : function (s: TSocket; lpBuffers: PWSABUF; dwBufferCount: DWORD;
                                lpNumberOfBytesRecvd: PDWORD; lpFlags: PDWORD; lpFrom: psockaddr;
                                lpFromlen: PInt; lpOverlapped: LPWSAOVERLAPPED;
                                lpCompletionRoutine: PWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE): u_int; stdcall;
  // <<

  // >> Replaced functions for intercepting TCP messages
    TrueConnect : function (s: TSocket; name: PSockAddr; namelen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    TrueSend    : function (s: TSocket; Buf : Pointer; len, flags: UINT): Integer; stdcall;
    TrueWsaRecv : function (s: TSocket; lpBuffers : PWSABUF; dwBufferCount : DWORD;
                            lpNumberOfBytesSent : LPDWORD; dwFlags : PDWORD; lpOverlapped : POVERLAPPED;
                            lpCompletionRoutine : Pointer ): Integer; stdcall;
  // <<

  // >> Other replaced functions; just for logging now
    TrueRecv      : function (s: TSocket; var Buf; len, flags: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    TrueRecvfrom  : function (s: TSocket; var Buf; len, flags: Integer; var from: TSockAddr;
                              var fromlen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
    TrueWsaSend   : function (s: TSocket; lpBuffers : PWSABUF; dwBufferCount : DWORD;
                              lpNumberOfBytesSent : LPDWORD; dwFlags : DWORD; lpOverlapped : POVERLAPPED;
                              lpCompletionRoutine : Pointer ): Integer; stdcall;
    TrueGethostbyname : function (name: PChar): PHostEnt; stdcall;
    TrueAccept        : function (s: TSocket; addr: PSockAddr; var addrlen: Integer): TSocket; stdcall;
    TrueWsaAccept     : function (s: TSOCKET; addr: psockaddr; addrlen: PINT; lpfnCondition: PCONDITIONPROC;
                                  dwCallbackData: DWORD): TSOCKET; stdcall;
  // <<

function NewSendTo(s: TSocket; Buf : Pointer; len, flags: Integer; var addrto: TSockAddr;
    tolen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  addrtoNew : TSockAddr;
  buffer : array of byte;
  dst : word;

begin           

  // determine destination address
  if addrto.sin_addr.S_addr = u_long($FFFFFFFF) then
    dst := $FFFF
  else if  (addrto.sin_addr.S_un_w.s_w1 = $000A) then
    dst := addrto.sin_addr.S_un_w.s_w2
  else
  begin
    // weird situation...  just emulate standard behavior
    result := TrueSendTo(s, Buf, len, flags, addrto, tolen);
    exit;
  end;

  // initialize structure for new address
  Move(addrto, addrtoNew, sizeOf(TSockAddr));

  // change destination ip
  addrtoNew.sin_addr.S_addr := $0100007F; // = 127.0.0.1

  // change destination port
  addrtoNew.sin_port := $E117;

  // create new data with additional destination address in it
  SetLength(buffer, len+2);
  Move(Buf^, buffer[0], len);
  Move(dst, buffer[len], 2);

  // send modified package
  result := TrueSendTo(s, @buffer[0], len+2, flags, addrtoNew, tolen);

end;

function NewWSARecvFrom(s: TSocket; lpBuffers: PWSABUF; dwBufferCount: DWORD;
    lpNumberOfBytesRecvd: PDWORD; lpFlags: PDWORD; lpFrom: psockaddr;
    lpFromlen: PInt; lpOverlapped: LPWSAOVERLAPPED;
    lpCompletionRoutine: PWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE): u_int; stdcall;
begin

  result := TrueWsaRecvFrom(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesRecvd, lpFlags, lpFrom,
    lpFromlen, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);

  // ignore recevies with optional lpFrom
  if (lpFrom = nil) or (lpFromlen = nil) or (lpFromlen^ = 0) then
    exit;

  // change only our packages
  if lpFrom.sin_addr.S_addr <> $0100007F then
  begin
    log(ModuleName, 'Unknown package sender');
    exit;
  end;

  // replace source ip
  lpFrom.sin_addr.S_un_w.s_w1 := $000A;
  move(PByteArray(lpBuffers.buf)[lpNumberOfBytesRecvd^ - 2], lpFrom.sin_addr.S_un_w.s_w2, 2);

  // data size should be smaller by 2 bytes (without source id)
  lpNumberOfBytesRecvd^ := lpNumberOfBytesRecvd^ - 2;

end;

function NewConnect(s: TSocket; name: PSockAddr; namelen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
var
  newName : TSockAddr;
  dst     : word;
  dstFile : TextFile;

begin

  // determine destination address
  if (name.sin_addr.S_un_w.s_w1 = $000A) then
    dst := name.sin_addr.S_un_w.s_w2
  else
  begin
    // connection to non-LAN host; just emulate standard behavior
    result := TrueConnect(s, name, namelen);
    exit;
  end;

  // write destination address into the temporarily file
  AssignFile(dstFile, 'temp.dll.dst');
  Rewrite(dstFile);
  Writeln(dstFile, dst);
  CloseFile(dstFile); 

  // change destination address and port
  move(name^, newName, sizeOf(TSockAddr));
  newName.sin_addr.S_addr := $0100007F;
  newName.sin_port        := $E117;

  // call standard method
  result := TrueConnect(s, @newName, namelen);
end;

function NewRecv(s: TSocket; var Buf; len, flags: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueRecv(s, Buf, len, flags);
end;

function NewRecvfrom(s: TSocket; var Buf; len, flags: Integer; var from: TSockAddr;
  var fromlen: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueRecvfrom(s, Buf, len, flags, from, fromlen);
end;

function NewWsaSend(s : TSocket; lpBuffers : PWSABUF; dwBufferCount : DWORD; lpNumberOfBytesSent : LPDWORD;
  dwFlags : DWORD; lpOverlapped : POVERLAPPED; lpCompletionRoutine : Pointer ): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueWsaSend(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
end;

function NewWsaRecv(s : TSocket; lpBuffers : PWSABUF; dwBufferCount : DWORD; lpNumberOfBytesSent : LPDWORD;
  dwFlags : PDWORD; lpOverlapped : POVERLAPPED; lpCompletionRoutine : Pointer ): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueWsaRecv(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
end;

function NewSend(s: TSocket; Buf : Pointer; len, flags: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueSend(s, Buf, len, flags);
end;

function NewGethostbyname(name: PChar): PHostEnt; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueGethostbyname(name);
end;

function NewAccept(s: TSocket; addr: PSockAddr; var addrlen: Integer): TSocket; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueAccept(s, addr, addrlen);
end;

function NewWsaAccept(s: TSOCKET; addr: psockaddr; addrlen: PINT;
    lpfnCondition: PCONDITIONPROC; dwCallbackData: DWORD): TSOCKET; stdcall;
begin
  result := TrueWsaAccept(s, addr, addrlen, lpfnCondition, dwCallbackData);
end;

procedure replaceMethod(libName, method: String; newProc: pointer; var oldProc: pointer);
begin
  HookProc(PChar(libName), PChar(method), newProc, oldProc);
end;


initialization

  // replace methods
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'send',          @NewSend,          @TrueSend);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'sendto',        @NewSendTo,        @TrueSendTo);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'recv',          @NewRecv,          @TrueRecv);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'recvfrom',      @NewRecvfrom,      @TrueRecvfrom);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'WSASend',       @NewWsaSend,       @TrueWsaSend);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'WSARecv',       @NewWsaRecv,       @TrueWsaRecv);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'WSARecvFrom',   @NewWsaRecvFrom,   @TrueWsaRecvFrom);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'connect',       @NewConnect,       @TrueConnect);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'gethostbyname', @NewGethostbyname, @TrueGethostbyname);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'accept',        @NewAccept,        @TrueAccept);
  replaceMethod('ws2_32.dll', 'WSAAccept',     @NewWsaAccept,     @TrueWsaAccept);

finalization

  // release hooks
  UnhookCode(@TrueSend);
  UnhookCode(@TrueSendTo);
  UnhookCode(@TrueRecv);
  UnhookCode(@TrueRecvfrom);
  UnhookCode(@TrueWsaSend);
  UnhookCode(@TrueWsaRecv);
  UnhookCode(@TrueWsaRecvFrom);
  UnhookCode(@TrueConnect);
  UnhookCode(@TrueGethostbyname);
  UnhookCode(@TrueAccept);
  UnhookCode(@TrueWsaAccept);

end.
```

Comment: And where does it fail? You have unicode 'modulepath' and calling 'lstrcpy' to copy it to 'LibraryName'.

Comment: I can see Char, PChar and string. Do you know anything about the Unicode changes in D2009?

Comment: And have unicode 'LibraryName', and calling 'LoadLibraryA'.

Comment: I know Char in D2009+ has become 2 bytes vs 1 and as pchar is after all pointer to dynamic array of char and string now is UT-16 instead of ANSI-8, am I missing anything?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't know where it fails, just the packets don't get routed. No exceptions or errors. Also the dll compiled in xe-3 weighs in at 954KB whereas in d2007 only 94KB.

Comment: Yes you have missed something. You are still calling LoadLibraryA. But passing UTF-16 data. It might just work if you change to  `LoadLibraryW`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you. That was of great help! Thanks again.

Comment: Also, that's a pretty weird hook. Why are you spewing all that asm at the remote thread?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz `lstrcpy` is Unicode. Look at it in Windows.pas. It's mapped to `lstrcpyW` in the standard way.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the asm avoids most virus scanners from detecting it in my particular scenario.